# why is this filename parameter a char pointer instead of string?

Tags: c++, c++14

There's a function provided by my uni that is supposed to read in a file. In the parameter, there's the fileName parameter. What I don't understand is why they're using a character pointer instead of a simple string?

Also, how would I call this function with a string filename then?

I'm running C++14 on Visual studio 2017 community edition.

```
double* read_text(char *fileName, int sizeR, int sizeC)
{
    double* data = new double[sizeR*sizeC];
    int i = 0;
    ifstream myfile(fileName);
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {

        while (myfile.good())
        {
            if (i > sizeR*sizeC - 1) break;
            myfile >> *(data + i);
            i++;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";
    //cout << i;
    return data;
}
```

Edit: I get it guys, it's stupid. I'll post a separate question then. Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: There's no reason for it to be a `char*`, and an non `const` one at that. Older versions of `ifstream` take a `const char*`, but a `std::string` can be converted to that easily, so you could just as easily have `read_text` take a `const std::string& fileName` then call `ifstream myFile(fileName.c_str()`. Modern versions of C++ (11 onwards?) have updated `ifstream` to take a `std::string` instead

Comment: Given `double* data = new double[sizeR*sizeC];` and `while (myfile.good())`, I'd suggest taking the code by this author with a grain of salt. Or a lump fo salt, maybe...

Comment: Yeah this is pretty terrible code. Its both old, doesn't use best practices, mixes c/c++ idioms and plain wrong in places.

Comment: (Incorrectly) checking for read errors and then silently returning uninitialized memory if they occur also seems particularly pointless.

Comment: Ask if you can get extra credit to fix this steaming pile of feces. Before doing that, take note whether the person you're asking is, in fact, the author, btw. You'll want to alter the verbiage a bit if that's the case.

Comment: Thank you for the fast replies guys. I understand that this is a completely stupid practice now. I'll post another question soon about why I can't simply change it to string then. Thanks!

Comment: If they are trying to teach you how not to do things, this code is an excellent example.

Comment: This code appears to me as bad instructions for your new remote control: "First close battery compartment. Second insert batteries"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why is this filename parameter a char pointer instead of string?

Because the designer of the API chose to do so. Most people at Stack Overflow are not the author of that API, so we cannot answer this question accurately.

However, there is another similar question that we can answer: What are reasons to use character pointer as a string argument? Let me answer that question instead:

- Not using `std::string` as an argument allows the user of the API to not create a `std::string` object. This may be useful when:

  - The API needs to be used in "freestanding" implementations that don't provide the standard library and thus have no `std::string`. This probably doesn't apply to your particular example since the implementation of the function uses the standard library, but I include this argument for completeness.
  - The API needs to be used on systems that provide no dynamic memory allocation, which `std::string` requires.
  - The dynamic memory allocation that creation of the string may require may be too slow in the context where the API is used (this won't apply to an API that is going to read from disk, but I include the argument here for completeness).
- (`const`) `char*` makes it possible to use the API from C. This may be relevant because:

  - The API may have originally been written for C, and has been inherited to a code base that now uses C++, but the API has not been changed in order to maintain backwards compatibility.
  - Providing a C compatible API allows using the API from other languages that are able to interface with C. Many languages have support for C interfaces while very few languages have support for C++ interfaces.

> Also, how would I call this function with a string filename then?

You can get a pointer to a null terminated string using the `c_str` member function. Unfortunately the API is badly designed and the argument is non-const, while the pointer returned by `c_str` is const. You can const_cast the constness of the argument away in order to call this function. This is "OK" because the function doesn't actually modify the pointed string.

If you can require C++17 standard and the source string is non-const, then the `data` member function will be simpler as it doesn't require const_cast. Prior to C++17 there was no non-const overload, so it would require the same const casting, and prior to C++11 the pointed string was not guaranteed to be null terminated.

To make it clear: Using a non-const string argument for this function is bad design - whether that argument is a character pointer to null terminated string, or a reference to `std::string`.

---

P.S.There are other, more serious problems:

- The caller of the function cannot possibly know how many numbers were read from the file. There is no way of avoiding UB in case the file has less than `sizeR*sizeC` values.
- Returning a bare pointer that owns dynamic memory resource is a very bad design.
- The loop that reads from the file checks whether the read was successful *after* the value has already been added to the array and the value is never overwritten, so the last element written into the array is always has an unspecified value.

Comment: Is there a freestanding implementation that provides `std::ifstream`, but not `std::string`?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I wouldn't expect that there would be.